# Exception using expression to set datetime field in MySQL and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I'm unable to get a parameterized SQL statement to execute on a table called `feeds`.

The table is defined as such;

```
CREATE TABLE `feeds` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_changed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `next` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `delta` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Here is the SQL statement.

> UPDATE `feeds` SET `feeds`.`delta`=@0,`feeds`.`next`=@1,`feeds`.`last_changed`=@2 WHERE id = 19 LIMIT 1

The error is on parameter `@1` when I try to use an expression as the value. Here's the value.

> (2013-05-22 11:58:57 + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)

This generates the following error.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Incorrect datetime value: '(2013-05-22 11:58:57 + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)' for column 'next' at row 1

I've tried putting the datetime in quotes, but that didn't help.

This is how I execute the SQL command in `C#`.

```
ICollection<object> pParameters = ......
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(pSql, conn);
cmd.Prepare();
int i = 0;
foreach (object obj in pParameters)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@{0}", i.ToString()), obj);
    i++;
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only put values into the parameters, not expressions. Try changing your query to this:

```
UPDATE feeds
SET feeds.delta=@0,feeds.next=@1,feeds.last_changed=@2  + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
WHERE id = 19 LIMIT 1
```

And then set the parameter as the date date/time value only - for example `2013-05-22 11:58:57`.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't know this. That kind of sucks I'll have to make a design change to handle expressions.

Answer (score 2):

if the datetime Parameter comes from c#, you should just use

```
DateTime.AddMinutes(<yourdateTimeParameter>, 15);
```

Comment: thanks, I uses the expression cause it was easier to change the units at runtime.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini why ? What does it change ?

Comment: The code is part of a feature that is configurable (minutes, hours, days, etc).

Comment: @MathewFoscarini well, that should be almost the same with both solutions, but anyway, don't need to change if you find a working solution.

Comment: well, I don't think a `switch` statement would add much work.